# Creating a debug app

Tags: android, debugging, failed-installation

Okay so i have an application, put up on the playstore.

What i want now, it to create the same application but with debug postfix in the name and it must have everything same.
I want to do this, because i do not want to disturb my original project when i am experimenting stuff,

So what i did was, i copied the project folder from wherever it was to the desktop, original one had the package name com.femindharamshi.spa so i refactored the whole thing to com.femindharamshidebug.spadebug and all changed the app_name in string

but when i try to open this app in the emulator, Android Studio Gives me the following error :

> Installation failed with message Failed to finalize session :
>   INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: Split_lib_slice_4_apk was defined multiple
>   times. It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an
>   existing version of the apk, if it is present, and then re-installing

Also i do not want to uninstall the original app from the emulator/physical device, i just want to add this app for testing purposes. What should i do ?

Answer (score 1):

Try closing the Android Studio and giving clean and build to the project.

Comment: well that works !! TYSM! but still i am facing a small but noticeable problem!

when i run the original app from android studio it replaces the debug app on the emulator and when i run the debugl app it replaces the original app on the emulator.. how can i keep both ?

Comment: Check the package name in AndroidManifest.xml file. The package name should be different for both the applications

Comment: Yes, i re-checked, its different, also i refactored the package name, so it changed throughout the project, still it would replace the app

Answer (score 0):

change you application ID in app level build.gradle file and sync the project

```
applicationId "//pkg id here"
```